# Custom Formula in Conditional Formatting to Include Multiple Words - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm looking for 2 custom formulas in Google Sheets, Conditional Formatting that will allow me to add multiple words. 1) Color the cell green if the cell contains apple, orange, taco, north, east, and west. But, the cell should exclude those words when they are contained within words, numbers, or any special characters; for example, greenapple, bloodorange, mildtaco2, -northeast, and /west/. It should also color the cell green when the word has a space before and after it. 2) I need the same formula as above, but one that can also exclude certain words using the same include conditions as above. And, I need to be able to easily add new words to include and exclude from both. Thank you!

Comment: Please ask 1 question at a time. Provide example sheet where applicable. Be precise in defining your input parameters and the desired output. For example, refrain from being vague with "can also exclude *certain* words". 
Consult guide on [minimal, viable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as needed. All in all, please do not be lazy when formulating questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **Conditional Formatting** ➝ **Custom formula**

```js
=NOT(ISNA(REGEXEXTRACT(" "&C1&" "," "&JOIN(" | ",{"apple","orange","taco","north","east","west"})&" ")))
```

[image]

**Note:** Change C1 in the formula according to your range

---

2. Use **Conditional Formatting** ➝ **Custom formula**

```js
=NOT(ISNA(REGEXEXTRACT(" "&G1&" "," "&JOIN(" | ",{"apple","orange","taco","north","east","west"})&" ")))
 *ISNA(REGEXEXTRACT(" "&G1&" "," "&JOIN(" | ",{"-northeast","/west/","mildtaco2","greenapple","bloodorange"})&" "))
```

[image]

**Note:** Change G1 in the formula according to your range